# Is there a way to make automatic spacing between each input in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to make my input in an EditText for example 1234 looks like 1 2 3 4 , basically to have automatic spacing between each input character?

Comment: Are you looking for the characters to have padding? Or are you looking to insert actual space characters? For example, suppose with `1 2 3 4`, the user has the text entry cursor after the `4`. They press the backspace key, which removes the `4`. If they press the backspace key again, are they removing the `3` (and the space between `3 4` was padding), or are they removing the space (because the space itself was a character)?

Comment: Yes every backspace removes the input  , the space is just for visual purposes, so the space is not a character itself.

Comment: Add a `TextWatcher` and do this programatically in `onTextChangeListener`. Add an space when each text is added and remove two when a number/text is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`android:letterSpacing`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:letterSpacing) or [the corresponding Java method `setLetterSpacing()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing%28float%29).